# Getting a pathname with .xml in it with YII?

Tags: yii

I have a controller called "SitemapController". This easily maps to this url:

```
 /sitemap
```

However, I need that link to also work if you open

```
/sitemap.xml
```

How do I map it in YII so the system can use both?

Comment: what happens if you use this now ? /sitemap.xml

Comment: Path not found. But I added the route as per the suggestion and it worked.

Comment: Would love to know why I got a downvote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve it like below by editing config file ,

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            'sitemap/*'=>'sitemap/index',
            'sitemap.xml/*'=>'sitemap/index',

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Now it will map routes to sitemap/someKey/someValue/..

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your url routing `'sitemap' => array('site/sitemap', 'urlSuffix'=>'.xml'),`

Comment: It should do if you put it at the end of your routing rules. Yii will use the first rule that works, so should find both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your **url manager** in config/main.php this way,

'site/sitemap.xml'=>'site/sitemap',

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
                            'site/sitemap.xml'=>'site/sitemap',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `.htaccess` add this rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml.*$ http://example.com/sitemap/ [R=301,L]
```